# How to provide automatic overview map in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, layouts

This is a slightly badly phrased question I know, but I'm not really sure what to call this. My supervisor recently showed me a printed out map that he had produced with a high-resolution satellite image on one side, and then an overview map of the whole of the UK on the other side, with a dot marking the location of the satellite image.

He said that this was produced automatically using ArcGIs, and he didn't have to manually add a point to the overview map with the right co-ordinates.

Unfortunately he has been unable to find time to help me with this, and I have been looking for how to do this, but as I don't know the name of this process it is very difficult to find it.

Does anyone have any ideas what this process/technique is called, and how I should go about doing it?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.

Comment: Waw I was looking at this as well.Thanks for the detailed answer

Comment: How To Add a Locator Map in ArcGis https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qz2JTeZlbQk

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. You have to add an extra Data Frame (Insert menu -> Data Frame) to contain your overview map.
2. Then you add layers to your new Data Frame - the ones you would like your overview map to contain.
3. Then you double click your Data Frame name in the Table of Contents at the left of ArcMap to access the Data Frame Properties.
4. Click the "Extent Indicators" tab and press the >> button in the middle. This will move the Layers (the name of your other Data Frame) post from the left side list to the right side list, telling ArcMap, that you want to show the extent of your Data Frame Layers in your new Data Frame. You can press the "Frame..." button, if you want to change the symbol of the extent rectangle.
5. Press "OK".
6. Change to Layout View (View menu -> Layout View).
7. Place your two Data Frames on the page as you like.
8. Now try zoom and pan in your detailed map, and see, that your overview map "follows" the navigation you make.

Enjoy