# Seeking ArcGIS Desktop tutorials?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, references

I'm looking for a good way to learn more ArcGIS techniques than I came across in my undergraduate Geography degree to really use the power of the software.

Browsing around and asking questions on this site has helped quite a bit e.g. I did not realised that you could link dataframes together, or even that you could have multiple data frames ([see [How to provide automatic overview map in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3658/how-to-provide-automatic-overview-map-arcgis-10)).

Similarly, I suspect there are lots of ArcGIS features that could really make my life easier, but that I just don't know about e.g. geodatabases.

What I'm really looking for are tutorial recommendations, in any medium (books, videos, websites, whatever). Obviously free or cheap are better, but I do have a budget for books as part of my PhD. As I probably hinted at above, I'm more interested in general usage of ArcGIS rather than specific tools (like DEM processing or route-finding), and something that is relatively structured would be good, so that I can work through it in a sensible order.

I know this is a bit of a tall order, but any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

Ensure you have **ArcTutor** installed (comes with ArcGIS Desktop install)

[Start doing the tutorials.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00v20000000t000000.htm/)

Id also advise paying a trip to the [ESRI Virtual Campus.](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm)
- Plenty of free training on there to get you started.

Go to [video.esri.com](http://video.esri.com/) for inspiration.

Answer (score 4):

Understanding your data (projection, attributes, formats) then you can using ArcGIS in some quite amazing ways..

General Usage :
For a good basis of understanding a geodatabase.
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/pdf/Building_Geodatabases_Tutorial.pdf
(yes 9.3 but still worth the look - good starting point)

Focus on: 
Subtypes and Domains (and validation spatial data)
Relationships between objects.
Topology - very powerful in controlling spatial features and their relationships.

for ArcGIS 10
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_geodatabase_design/003n0000000z000000/

If have access to MS Visio you can see the structure of the Geodatabase
http://resources.arcgis.com/content/data-models

For really fancy stuff (making gis data look nice) look into **Representations**
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_are_representations/008t00000002000000/
which is tied to spatial data (keeping the topological) structure but represent the data in a more human (cartographic) form.

The most advanced and powerful part of ArcGIS is the **Geoprocessing** tools that can be automated to do serious amounts of analysis.
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_advanced_techniques_in_ModelBuilder/002w0000005q000000/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would suggests, to start from help of Arcgis. You will find a lot of examples and tutorials.

For videos you can find some in youtube channel of esri and more in other channels:

http://www.youtube.com/esritv

You mension about Geodatabaseis, a good idea to start is the book of ESRI (i know is theoretical but sometimes you need it):

[Designing geodatabases: case studies in GIS data modeling](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=85&moduleID=0)

and free from google...:

[Designing geodatabases: case studies in GIS data modeling](http://books.google.com/books?id=3g62f8RkUXQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=designing+geodatabases&source=bl&ots=SDCYMKPqJo&sig=_le1VG12e3tw0bVoqY5WoYmXsxM&hl=el&ei=BN7oTKriKNaAhAfwwpmMDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Very good books with tutorials is:

[GIS Tutorial 1: Basic Workbook](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=184&moduleID=0)

[GIS Tutorial 2: Spatial Analysis Workbook](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=185&moduleID=0)

[GIS Tutorial 3: Advanced Workbook](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=186&moduleID=0)

In some forums you can take some ideas:

http://www.cartotalk.com/

Answer (score 1):

One option would be the [ESRI Virtual Campus](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm). There are free training tutorials and many that are pay-as-you-go.

[knowgis.com](http://www.knowgis.com) has many free tutorials.  They also have an entire training series.

Many colleges including Harvard have GIS tutorials and exercises.  Visit : http://hcl.harvard.edu/libraries/maps/gis/tutorials.cfm

Answer (score 1):

ESRI has a basic GIS course [Learning ArcGIS Desktop for ArcGIS 10](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&CourseID=1942).

[Knowgis.com](http://www.KnowGIS.com) is really good.  I have their two-day professional training series and found it to be useful.