# Free GIS workshops, tutorials, and applied learning material

Tags: references, education

This Q&A lists free as in $0 workshops in GIS and related fields that have their material available to view or download online. The list is not limited to FOSS GIS, as GISers usually use a combination of open and closed source tools to accomplish their tasks. Some of these tools are easier than others and some are better documented. This list will be a great benefit to the community especially for new comers to the field.

## General GIS

- [GIS Project Video Tutorial on Acquiring, Analyzing, and Mapping US Census Data in QGIS](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCuEIQl2BByhnFWu858xy5O0rfVAI94Hw) from [@A.S](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/17268/a-s)
- [GIS Tutor: Beginner / Intermediate Level GIS](http://www.gistutor.com/) from [@radek](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/173/radek)
- [BostonGIS](http://bostongis.com/) from [@simo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1370/simo)
- [Lectures on GIS for the Social Sciences](http://www.gis.unbc.ca/courses/geog204/index.php) from [@ubernatural](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/4908/ubernatural)

## Open-source GIS

- [OpenGEO Education Center](http://workshops.opengeo.org/) from [@radek](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/173/radek)
- [QGIS Videos (faunitalia)](http://www.youtube.com/user/faunalia) from [@simo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1370/simo)
- [GIS SE Question: Geoserver Tutorials](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/7987/127) from [@com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/465/com)
- [GIS SE Question: Open Source Training Materials](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/13982/127) from [@MarkIreland](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/454/mark-ireland)
- [QGIS for Newbies](http://learnpracticalgis.com/quantum-gis-tutorial/) from [@IanAllan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/7259/ian-allan)

## ESRI Products

- [GIS SE Question: Best place for (structured) ArcGIS tutorials](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3696/127) from [@robintw](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/102/robintw)
- [ArcGIS Automation and Programming](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/) from [@Bethany](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/4919/bethany)

## Transportation

These links include either theoretical or applied transportation knowledge in transportation planning

- [GIS primer for Transportation](http://www.giscafe.com/Vision/June01/June01_Book_GIS-T.pdf)
- [Transit Capacity and Quality of Service Manual](http://www.trb.org/Main/Blurbs/153590.aspx)
- [UrbanSim: FOSS Urban development, socio economic, and land use planning package](http://www.urbansim.org/Community/UrbanSimWorkshop2011Athens)
- [MOVES(Motor Vehicle Emission Simulator) Workshop and technical background](http://www.epa.gov/otaq/models/moves/movesback.htm)
- [Transit GIS tutorials](http://www.transitgis.org/tutorials/)
- [Remote sensing in transportation workshop](http://www.ncgia.ucsb.edu/ncrst/meetings/20030415MSN/first.html)
- [Florida's CBT planning model explained](http://www.fsutmsonline.net/images/uploads/Development_of_CBT.pdf)

## Disaster Management

- [Geo-information Technology for Crisis Management](http://ocw.tudelft.nl/courses/geomatics/geo-information-technology-for-crisis-management/lectures/)

## Databases

- [Spatial Database Course Material](http://www.comp.dit.ie/pbrowne/Spatial%20Databases%20SDEV4005/Spatial%20Databases%20SDEV4005.htm) from [@radek](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/173/radek)

## Geo Statistics

- [Learn R Lectures and Classes](http://www.fort.usgs.gov/brdscience/learnR.htm)
- [Geodatabase Mining Course](http://edugi.uni-muenster.de/eduGI/downloads/03/eduGI%20elearning.htm) from [@radek](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/173/radek)
- [A Practical Guide to Geostatistical Mapping](http://spatial-analyst.net/book/)

Answer (score 13):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

- [OpenGeo Education Center](http://workshops.opengeo.org/) offers materials focusing mostly on web mapping using PostgreSQL/PostGIS, GeoServer and javascript (OpenLayers and GeoExt)
- Not really a workshop, but [GISTutor](http://www.gistutor.com/) is good source of begginer/intermediate level tutorials.
- E-Learning materials from [Geospatial Data Mining](http://edugi.uni-muenster.de/eduGI/downloads/03/eduGI%20elearning.htm) course (eduGI.net - International Network for Education in Geographic Information Science).
- [Spatial Databases](http://www.comp.dit.ie/pbrowne/Spatial%20Databases%20SDEV4005/Spatial%20Databases%20SDEV4005.htm) course materials (School of Computing, Dublin Institute of Technology)
- [An introduction to Open Source Geospatial Information Systems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GBqeEXII4U) - talk by Gavin Jackson @ [OSDC 2011](http://osdc.com.au/)
- [Broom Spatial R Class](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9577903/broomspatial.pdf) notes from [Frank Davenport](http://davenportspatialanalytics.squarespace.com/blog/2012/6/19/notes-from-a-recent-spatial-r-class-i-gave.html)

Answer (score 11):

- The [bostongis](http://bostongis.com/) website provides many tutorials and *quick guides* regarding PostGIS, SQL Server 2008 and spatial analyses, openlayers, OSM and openlayers and some more.
- The [faunitalia youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/faunaliagis) gives video tutorial regarding Qgis and plugins

Answer (score 6):

Though there may also be other lecture series at different University websites, the UNBC site has some good content, particularly for beginning users:

http://www.gis.unbc.ca/courses/geog204/index.php

Other courses besides GEOG 204 are listed in the menu on the left-hand side.

Along the same lines as academic content (rather than workshops per se, but still useful), Google books has a number of free items related to GIS:

http://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=gis&btnG=

Answer (score -1):

There's a new Coursera MOOC (starting today, Feb 22nd, 2016) called [Geographic Information Systems (GIS) Specialization](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/gis) and is offered by UC Davis.

It's geared towards beginners, and gives participants 1 year license to some ESRI product.

If you're reading this in the future, see if the specialization or any of its courses are given again.